# Nuxt 3 cant see my website after i build docker image and docker run it?

Tags: node.js, docker, nuxt.js

Hello Here is my problem:

I can see my image locally however when I do “docker run -p 3000:3000 website-name”, then go to “localhost:3000”, my Nuxt 3 website doesn’t come up.

The container logs tell me that it is "Listening http://[::]:3000 "

```
here is my docker file : # Dockerfile
FROM node:18-alpine

create destination directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/nuxt-app
WORKDIR /usr/src/nuxt-app

update and install dependency
RUN apk update && apk upgrade
RUN apk add git

copy the app, note .dockerignore
COPY . /usr/src/nuxt-app/
RUN yarn install
RUN yarn build

EXPOSE 3000

ENV NUXT_HOST=0.0.0.0
ENV NUXT_PORT=3000
ENV API_PROXY_URL=“example”
ENV SECURE_TOKEN=“example”
ENV MADRILL_AUTH_USER=“example”
ENV MADRILL_AUTH_PASS=“example”
ENV ADMIN_EMAIL=“example”
ENV PASSWORD_CHILDREN=“ETHOS-CHILDREN”

ENV NODE_OPTIONS=“–max_old_space_size=4096”

CMD [“node”, “.output/server/index.mjs”]
```